# How to prevent automatic forwarding to OSX Server Wiki?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, osx-server

Im trying to use OSX Server Mountain Lion for the first time and came to the following problem:

I registered a new domain and linked it to my ip address via an A-entry at united-domains. On my mountain lion server I activated "Websites" and "Wiki". When I only activate the Websites, I come to my Server website, where I can read a short introduction about the Server. When I activate both services, I will allways be forwarded to the wiki page. Why?

How can I prevent this?

Another thing beside: The Server is at my home and behind an "Alice DSL"-Router. Calling my domain from inside my network with my PCs next to the server always results a forwarding to the configuration page of the router. How to change this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it:

When you do not run your own web page on the server, it automatically links to the wiki pages. I tried to upload an html file into the webservices default directory and run into the problem, that i did not have the permissions for that.

I checked the group wheel, because it has permissions on the folder. The strange thing is, that it has only read permissions on the directory.

I used

```
chown -R user:wheel directory/
```

to make me to the owner of the directory, so that i have rwx access.

Then I was able to upload files and came directly to them.